# Excel JS custom function does not return a matrix

Tags: excel, office-js, custom-functions-excel

I am trying to implement an Excel custom function (JavaScript) that returns a matrix of strings.

According to [Create custom functions in Excel (Preview)](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/excel/custom-functions-overview) the resultDimensionality has to be set to [matrix](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/excel/customfunctionsenumerations) in this case.

To keep it simple I've just copied the example from the documentation to return such an array of arrays:

```
function getstringmatrix () {
    return [["first","row"],["second","row"],["third","row"]];
}    
Excel.Script.CustomFunctions["MYFUNCTIONS"]["GETSTRINGMATRIX"] = {
    call: getstringmatrix,
    result: {
        resultType: Excel.CustomFunctionValueType.string,
        resultDimensionality: Excel.CustomFunctionDimensionality.matrix,
    },
    parameters: [ ],
    options:{ batch: false, stream: false }
};
```

When inserting the function =MYFUNCTIONS.GETSTRINGMATRIX() into an Excel cell this cell is filled with the string "first". But the expected second column and the other two rows are not filled at all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function you've created should be used in an [Array Formula](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7) in Excel. Array formulas are an advanced type of formula that require the user to enter them in a specific way.

1. First, select the range of cells where you want the formula output to go (in your case, select a 3-row, 2-column range)
2. Then type the formula: `=MYFUNCTIONS.GETSTRINGMATRIX()`
3. Then type Ctrl+Shift+Enter. That's the standard way of entering array formulas in Excel.

There are native functions in Excel that also return arrays in this way, such as `=LINEST()`.

Of course, functions that take ranges as input don't require any special way to enter them - only functions that output arrays need the user to do something special.

Comment: Thanks Michael. Sure, but wouldn't it be better to also provide a way of inserting a "normal" formula, and in case this formula returns a matrix, Excel automatically displays this as an Array Formula?

You already demonstrated such a feature in your video [Microsoft Ignite Custom Functions](https://myignite.microsoft.com/videos/54708) at 6:40 when inserting =CFACTORY.TRACKTEMPERATURE(G1). This formula automatically fills several cells. That's exactly what I want to achieve.

Comment: Ha, that's very observant! Yes, I didn't use an array formula in my demo. That's a feature we're still working on and haven't released. I don't have details like dates, but your "matrix"-output custom functions will be much easier to use in the future ;)

Comment: Any progress on this? - as trying to do Ctrl+Shift+Enter in the web version of Excel doesn't appear to do anything.  I would have expected the documented "matrix" return type to be implemented in some form by now?

Comment: Just found that this does work as intended in the Desktop Excel Office Insider build but doesn't yet work in the Web Client.